# Verify the following for the given complex metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The space of complex-valued continuous functions on the interval $I=[0,1]$ can be made an inner product metric space by means of the definition :

$$<f,g> = \int_0^1 f(t){g(t)}^-$$ where $g(t)^-$ is the complex conjugate of g

and $$||f||=\sqrt{<f,f>}\\ d(f,g)=||f-g||$$

Verify the following(My approach):

(1) $||f-g||=0$ implies $f=g$ So,

$||f-g||^2 = <f-g,f-g>  = ||f||^2+<f,g> -<g,f> - ||g||^2$

But couldn't conclude from here.

(2) $<f,g> + <g,f>  \ \le 2||f|| ||g||$

Couldn't find anything here.

(3) $||f+g|| \le ||f|| + ||g||$ 
Simply asking me to prove the triangle approach, We can easily find that cauchy scwharz holds for this metric, I will try proving the triangle inequality by using the cauchy inequality.

Found out that :

$$||f+g||^2 = <f+g,f+g> = ||f||^2 - ||g||^2 - \int_0^1 f(t)g(t)^- + \int_0^1 g(t)f(t)^-$$

Normally we would have two integrals of the saem sign and equal to eacher so I can then apply cauchy -schwarz etc. But in this case they are not equal, and two terms are negative and two terms are positive. Couldn't think of how to build up an inequality, any hints?

Comment: $||f||^2 = \langle f,f\rangle = \int |f(t)|dt$ which can only be $0$ when $f$ is, for continuous functions. The ||f-g|| statement is a corollary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there holds $||f-g||=0$. Pluging in the definition we get that:
$$
0=||f-g||^2=\int_0^1 |f-g|^2
$$
This is a (real) integral of a continuous function. Since the integral is $0$, the integrand, which is $\geq 0$, has to be $0$ as well. Therefore we conlcude $f=g$.

For the second expression you need to take absolute values first on the left hand side, otherwise the statement is not well defined (a complex number cant be smaller than a real number). Therefore we just apply the normal triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz twice:
$$
|<g,f>+<f,g>| \leq ||g||\; ||f|| + ||f||\; ||g||= 2||f||\; ||g||
$$

The triangle inequality is also a consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz. The calculation is a bit longer, but I will give you the most imporant hint:
$$
<u,v>^*+<u,v>=2Re(<u,v>) \\
|Re(<u,v>)| \leq |<u,v>|
$$
Can you carry on from there? If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: For the first part, why do we conclude that the integrand has to be 0 ? Can't the antiderivative of a continuous function have the property :

$F(1)=F(0)$

Comment: We have a function $\geq 0$, that is the key point.

Comment: I added it in my post as well.